# Flask-Admin: Populating a dropdown menu based off of a value in another table

Tags: flask, flask-admin

In my model definition, I have class A and class B.

```
class B(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    max_num = Column(Integer)

class A(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('B.id'))
    b = relationship('B')
    num = Column(Integer)`
```

In my Flask-Admin create form for A, I want to create a drop-down menu in which the options for num are limited to `[1, B.max_num]`.

For example, if I have `B(id=10,max_num=5)`, and when the user is creating A and selects that B with `id=10`, then the dropdown menu for num should be populated with 1,2,3,4,5.

Is this possible?

Comment: Nice crisp question, would love to know the answer too. +1

Comment: Using Flask-Admin u mean, Flask-Admin will add the forms to your Admin Area?